# Jenkins Pipeline fails at artifactory upload

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I am trying to upload files into Artifactory repo using my Jenkins file.
The pipeline fails at the Artifactory upload stage.

I'm using Jfrog-Artifactory Plugin version: 3.15.4.

```
#Pipeline Script
rtUpload (
   serverId: 'app1-artifactory',
   spec: """{
      "files": [
            {
                "pattern": "*app*.tar.gz",
                "target": "myrepo/${Artifactory_Directory}/${Bld_ID}/artifacts/"
            },
            {
                "pattern": "*app*.tar.Z",
                "target": "myrepo/${Artifactory_Directory}/${Bld_ID}/artifacts/"
            }
         ]
    }"""
)
```

```
#Error
java.lang.Exception: Error occurred during operation, please refer to logs for more information.
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.producerConsumer.ProducerConsumerExecutor.start(ProducerConsumerExecutor.java:85)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.util.spec.SpecsHelper.uploadArtifactsBySpec(SpecsHelper.java:101)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.GenericArtifactsDeployer$FilesDeployerCallable.invoke(GenericArtifactsDeployer.java:166)
Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to mymachine
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1800)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:356)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:1001)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1159)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1148)
        at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.common.executors.GenericUploadExecutor.execute(GenericUploadExecutor.java:56)
        at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.declarative.steps.generic.UploadStep$Execution.runStep(UploadStep.java:39)
        at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.declarative.steps.generic.UploadStep$Execution.runStep(UploadStep.java:24)
        at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.ArtifactorySynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.run(ArtifactorySynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:54)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed uploading artifacts by spec
    at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.GenericArtifactsDeployer$FilesDeployerCallable.invoke(GenericArtifactsDeployer.java:168)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.GenericArtifactsDeployer$FilesDeployerCallable.invoke(GenericArtifactsDeployer.java:117)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:3317)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:376)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(InterceptingExecutorService.java:78)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$$Lambda$8/0x000000008800fe60.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:825)
```

Sometimes on rebuilding the pipeline, it runs without errors and the files are uploaded to the repo successfully. What could be the issue?

Comment: What is the file which is being uploaded? Can you share also the log entries from Artifactory?(artifactory-request.log and artifactory-service.log), are the upload requests actually reach Artifactory?
Did the issue start happening after upgrade of the plugin?

Comment: Where can I find the Artifactory logs?

Comment: It depends on your Arti version but usually under $JFROG_HOME/var/log or for 6.x under $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an open issue https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-66424

Downgrading the Artifactory Plugin to version 3.10.5 is the workaround till the issue gets resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This is already opened issue on the Jenkins official websites

https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-66424

Please check the link.